# Using batch file to create new table in oracle/sqlplus

Tags: batch-file, sqlplus

I want create new table in `oracle` with `sqlplus` and `batch` file.

```
sqlplus user/password @create_tables.sql
```

it is successfully

but that's not what I want. I want the user to input year.
My batch file look like :

```
@echo off

set /p year=__YEAR (YYYY)?
sqlplus user/password
create table data%year%
(Nama varchar2(25),
value number);
echo Successfull
pause
```

script stops here

```
SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Sun Aug 25 06:07:26 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP and Data Mining options

SQL>
```

what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you have launched an interactive shell (with `SQL>` prompt) and when you exit from that, the batch interpreter will run the `create` line as a new command (and fail).

If there isn't any other way to do it, you could `echo` the required commands to a temporary `filename.sql` in `%temp%` and then call that. Syntax here might not be 100%, but I hope it's a starting point :

```
@echo off
set /p year=__YEAR (YYYY)?
  rem  Set command in temp file :
echo create table data%year% (Name varchar2(25), value number); > @%temp%\temp.sql
  rem  Now run the above command :
sqlplus user/password @%temp%\temp.sql
echo Successfull
pause
```

Comment: Thank U very much. i added **echo exit > @%temp%\temp.sql** syntax before **rem Now run the above command**. script work for me. thanks again.